# The EVT_CLOSE gets fired every time I click on wx.Frame or press key on keyboard

Tags: python, wxpython, wxwidgets

I am running following class every time I run my python script:

```
class MySplashScreen(wx.SplashScreen):
    def OnSplashScreenExit(self,e):
        self.Hide();
        frame = MyFrame(None)

    def __init__(self,parent=None):
        if "linux" in sys.platform or "darwin" in sys.platform:       
             bmp = wx.Bitmap(PATH + '/../icons/DNA.png', wx.BITMAP_TYPE_PNG)
        elif "win" in sys.platform and not 'darwin' in sys.platform:      
             bmp = wx.Bitmap(PATH + '\..\icons\DNA.png', wx.BITMAP_TYPE_PNG)       

        wx.SplashScreen.__init__(self,bmp,wx.SPLASH_CENTER_ON_SCREEN | wx.SPLASH_TIMEOUT,SPLASH_TIMEOUT,parent)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_CLOSE,self.OnSplashScreenExit)
```

But when I click anywhere on my MyFrame another MyFrames opens. While debugging I found that every time I click anywhere on MyFrame or press any key on keyboard, the function OnSplashScreenExit is run. Can someone help me fix this. This problem is not producible in linux. It occurs only on my windows 8.1 with python2.7 system.

Comment: You are creating MyFrame in OnSplashScreenExit, so that explains why a frame opens when the splash closes. Are you creating MyFrame somewhere else too?  It would help to see a running sample http://wiki.wxpython.org/MakingSampleApps

Answer (score 0):

I could fix it by making following change:

```
if "win" in sys.platform:
         self.OnSplashScreenExit("")
else:
         self.Bind(wx.EVT_CLOSE,self.OnSplashScreenExit)
```